# How to detect when app is not reopen from background on iOS in Delphi Firemonkey mobile app?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, background-process, pascal

I am developing a Delphi mobile app on both Android and iOS platforms where I want to carry out some action when the app is first launched, but not open from the background.

I have tried using `if AAppEvent <> TApplicationEvent.WillBecomeForeground` but it seems like the statement is not true when I first launch the app. Is there any way to let me detect when the app is first launched and when the app is opened from the background?

Comment: At what point do you want to detect the condition? You can handle the `BecameActive` event to know when the app has become visible. If you use a flag eg call it `IsLaunched`, and set it to `True` when you handle `BecameActive` only if it is `False` (which it will be the first time the event is handled) you'll know it was the _first_ time the app became active

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code :

```
class function TMainForm.ApplicationEventHandler(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
begin
  if AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.BecameActive then begin
    if fLaunchedInBackgroundState then begin
        fLaunchedInBackgroundState := False;
    end;
  end
  else if AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.FinishedLaunching then begin
    LaunchedInBackgroundState := TiOSHelper.SharedApplication.applicationState = UIApplicationStateBackground;
  end;
end;

initialization 
  LaunchedInBackgroundState := False;
  var LAppEventSvc: IFMXApplicationEventService;
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService, IInterface(LAppEventSvc)) then
    LAppEventSvc.SetApplicationEventHandler(TmainForm.ApplicationEventHandler);
```